# SLF4J - Logging regardless of the log level

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

In my Java application, I use SLF4J + Logback for logging. I use **DEBUG** level logging on development and **ERROR** level logging on the production environment. But there are some messages that I want to log in any case, regardless of the log level (similar to `System.out.println("Some Message")` but using logger).

Is there any practical way to achieve this? I can use error or lower levels, but what I want to do is to give some information, so `logger.error("Some message");` is semantically wrong, it is not an error.

I can define another logger in my `logback.xml` for my class/classes, but it is not convenient.

What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: I think that you can't. You have to give a log level to the message and it will only appear if the log level is set to that level or to a higher log level. You can't log something in any case. Except, as you have said, the lowest level, FATAL, but it will not be semantically correct.

Comment: I am aware that iif it have existed it would be wrong because it might be abused by libraries etc. and logging framework would be useless. But I still need that kind of functionality, there should be a "right" way of doing it.

Comment: It sounds like you've answered your own question.  Within your Java code, you want to log some messages at, say, the WARN level, so that they'll be logged in development but not in production.  Other messages you want to log all the time, so if you use the same logger, then in production, they'd have to be logged at least at level ERROR.  You will indeed need another logger if you want to log the messages at a lower level (like maybe ALL) and still have them appear in all environments.

Answer (score 3):

This is where the wonderful "Marker" feature of SLF4J/Logback comes in very handy. Say you want to log to the console all warnings/errors, as well as anything that's a special "Status" message.

You can have a class do logging like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final Marker status = MarkerFactory.getMarker("STATUS");
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    public void doSomething() {
        logger.info(status, "Beginning");
        logger.info("Regular info log");
        logger.warn("Warning");
        logger.info(status, "Done");
    }
}
```

Then, in logback.xml, you filter to show all warnings and messages marked "STATUS":

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
        <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
            <marker>STATUS</marker>
        </evaluator>
        <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
        <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
    </filter>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${pattern}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Basically, you have the logger's level be DEBUG so that *everything* goes to the appender, and then in the appender do further [filtering](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) to get the exact lines you're looking for. If you are trying to have more different logging levels for different classes it can get a bit trickier, but Logback gives a lot of flexibility with filters (and you can even make your own filters if needed) which lets one handle pretty much anything needed.

Comment: There is a serious problem with your suggestion. SLF4J's markers perform horribly - http://jira.qos.ch/browse/SLF4J-240 documents the problem. In testing we have done code that uses the SLF4J BasicMarker contains method (which OnMarkerEvaluator does) is 100-300 times slower than other filters.

Comment: @rgoers I haven't done performance testing and haven't had cases where my logging was a performance bottleneck, but it's good to keep in mind that if one is running into problems that a more-complex-than-average logging setup that uses Markers might be one. Thanks.

Comment: SLF4J-240 was fixed today and will be in the 1.7.24 release.